# How to use third party maven dependency on commandline?

Tags: java, maven

I have a private maven dependency (jar) in our Artifactory in the repository third party.
Now I want to use this jar like this:

```
mvn org.company:xxx-maven-plugin:0.0.4 -Dmaven.repo.remote=https://artifactory:443/third-party
```

But this fails with: `Could not find goal '0.0.4'`

How can I define in a maven command (not in the pom or something) to use a third party maven dependency from our artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you usually specify repositories in your `settings.xml`. The `maven.repo.remote` seems to be Maven 1.x syntax and I do not know whether it still works.

Secondly (and more importantly), you cannot just call a plugin, but you call a goal within that plugin. The syntax is:

```
groupId:artifactId:version:goal
```

Your line is missing the goal. You need to look up its name.